# Java Syntax Highlighting Issue for IntelliJ Ultimate

Tags: java, intellij-idea, syntax-highlighting

When I run the files in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate, I can getting improper syntax highlighting of only orange, green, and gray. Is there any way to get more colors for syntax highlighting for methods and variables like VSCode does?

This is my theme with One Dark Theme:

[image]

I want the theme to be like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Theme

I would suggest using [Atom One Dark](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12178-atom-onedark-theme/) as a theme. It's really colorful, so it makes easier to focus on (at least for me). You should give it a try.

### Reformatting

There is a setting about reformatting. You should try it. You can access it with CTRL+SHIFT+ALT+L.

Comment: I did try using Atom Dark Theme but it didn't become colorful. I updated my question to show the image with the Atom Dark Theme and I have posted a picture of what I wanted that code to look like.

Comment: The question is asking how to customize a color scheme, and is not asking about reformatting at all.

Comment: @skomisa please see the older version of the post.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the syntax coloring of an existing Scheme within Intellij IDEA:

- Press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>alt</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> to open the **Settings** screen, then select the scheme you want to modify from the **Scheme** drop list. I chose *Classic Light*.
- Navigate to **Editor > Color Scheme > Language Defaults**, or **Editor > Color Scheme > Java** if you want to restrict your customization to Java source only.
- Select the language feature for which you want to modify the color(s) under the main categories (i.e. *Classes*, *Comments*, *Identifiers*, etc.). For example, to modify the color for curly braces select *Braces and Operators*, then *Parentheses*.
- If the **Inherit values from** checkbox is displayed and checked, uncheck it to enable customization. Then check the foreground checkbox, click the color field to its right and select a color of your choice, then click <kbd>Apply</kbd>, <kbd>OK</kbd> to implement your change.

See below for the syntax coloring of some Java source, before and after color customization, showing changes such as dark pink italicized string literals, light blue curly braces, purple round brackets, orange class names, gold Java keywords and light green comments.

### Default coloring:

[image: Default coloring]

### Syntax coloring after modification:

[image: coloring after modification]

Notes:

- The ugly changes I made were just for demonstrating the approach, but the required changes shown in the question's screen shot should be straightforward to achieve.
- Selecting italicization for string literals had an unintended side effect. The display of the character 'ᚙ' was changed because there was no italic equivalent to render.
- If you mess things up completely, you can easily revert to the defaults. Click the settings cog wheel next to your Scheme name and select **Restore Defaults** from the popup menu:

  [image: Restore menu entry]
- A disappointing limitation with this approach is that all Java keywords must be the same color. That's why *import* and *package* and *public* and *throws* and *char* and *new* all have the same color in the Java source screen shot above.
- You can export your customization if you want to preserve or share it. Select **Export** from the context menu shown when you click the settings cog wheel. There is also an **Import Scheme** option.
- See [Colors and Fonts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-colors-and-fonts.html) in the Intellij IDEA documentation for more information.